# Not able to draw string in java game of TicTacToe

Tags: java, swing

I use just one class called Game. I am actually new to GUI .
It runs fine but if someone wins it doesn't draw string it should when it checks for the winner after every click. I'm not sure if it is a stupid question :|

```
package com.Myproject.main;



import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable , ActionListener
{
JButton x0y0 , x1y0 , x2y0 ;
JButton x0y1 , x1y1 , x2y1 ;
JButton x0y2 , x1y2 , x2y2 ;
int turn = 0;
Graphics g;
Thread thread = new Thread();
String symbolx0y0;
String symbolx1y0;
String symbolx2y0;
String symbolx0y1;
String symbolx1y1;
String symbolx2y1;
String symbolx0y2;
String symbolx1y2;
String symbolx2y2;
public Game()
{
    setSize(300 , 300);
    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    x0y0 = new JButton("Click me");
    x1y0 = new JButton("Click me");
    x2y0 = new JButton("Click me");
    x0y1 = new JButton("Click me");
    x1y1 = new JButton("Click me");
    x2y1 = new JButton("Click me");
    x0y2 = new JButton("Click me");
    x1y2 = new JButton("Click me");
    x2y2 = new JButton("Click me");
    x0y0.setBounds( 0 , 0 , 90 , 90);
    x1y0.setBounds( 91 , 0 , 90 , 90);
    x2y0.setBounds( 182 , 0 , 90 , 90);
    x0y1.setBounds( 0 , 91 , 90 , 90);
    x1y1.setBounds( 91 , 91 , 90 , 90);
    x2y1.setBounds( 182 , 91 , 90 , 90);
    x0y2.setBounds( 0 , 182 , 90 , 90);
    x1y2.setBounds( 91 , 182 , 90 , 90);
    x2y2.setBounds( 182 , 182 , 90 , 90);
    getContentPane().add(x0y0);
    getContentPane().add(x1y0);
    getContentPane().add(x2y0);
    getContentPane().add(x0y1);
    getContentPane().add(x1y1);
    getContentPane().add(x2y1);
    getContentPane().add(x0y2);
    getContentPane().add(x1y2);
    getContentPane().add(x2y2);
    x0y0.addActionListener(this);
    x1y0.addActionListener(this);
    x2y0.addActionListener(this);
    x0y1.addActionListener(this);
    x1y1.addActionListener(this);
    x2y1.addActionListener(this);
    x0y2.addActionListener(this);
    x1y2.addActionListener(this);
    x2y2.addActionListener(this);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {

    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Game game = new Game();

}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == x0y0)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x0y0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx0y0("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x0y0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx0y0("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x1y0)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x1y0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx1y0("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x1y0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx1y0("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x2y0)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x2y0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx2y0("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x2y0.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx2y0("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x0y2)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x0y2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx0y2("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x0y2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx0y2("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x1y2)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x1y2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx1y2("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x1y2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx1y2("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x2y2)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x2y2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx2y2("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x2y2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx2y2("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x0y1)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x0y1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx0y1("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x0y1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx0y1("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x1y1)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x1y1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx1y1("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x1y1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx1y1("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    if(e.getSource() == x2y1)
    {
        if(turn%2==0){
        x2y1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Circle.png"));
        turn++ ;
        setSymbolx2y1("Circle");
        return;
        }
        if(turn%2!=0){
         x2y1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/self/Cross.png"));
         turn++ ;
         setSymbolx2y1("Cross");
         return;
        }
    }
    checkWinner();
}
public void drawCircle(Graphics g){
g.drawString("Circle Won" , 30 , 30);
}
public void drawCross(Graphics g){
g.drawString("Cross Won" , 30 , 30);
}
 public void checkWinner(){
     if(symbolx2y0 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx1y1 == symbolx2y2 && symbolx2y2 == "Circle") drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx2y0 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx1y1 == symbolx2y2 && symbolx2y2 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx0y0 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx2y2 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx0y0 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx0y0 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx2y2 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx0y0 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx0y0 == symbolx1y0 && symbolx1y0 == symbolx2y0 && symbolx0y0 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx0y0 == symbolx1y0 && symbolx1y0 == symbolx2y0 && symbolx0y0 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx0y1 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx1y1 == symbolx2y1 && symbolx0y1 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx0y1 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx1y1 == symbolx2y1 && symbolx0y1 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx0y2 == symbolx1y2 && symbolx1y2 == symbolx2y2 && symbolx0y2 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx0y2 == symbolx1y2 && symbolx1y2 == symbolx2y2 && symbolx0y2 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx0y0 == symbolx0y1 && symbolx0y1 == symbolx0y2 && symbolx0y2 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx0y0 == symbolx0y1 && symbolx0y1 == symbolx0y2 && symbolx0y2 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx1y0 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx1y1 == symbolx1y2 && symbolx1y2 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx1y0 == symbolx1y1 && symbolx1y1 == symbolx1y2 && symbolx1y2 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
     if(symbolx2y0 == symbolx2y1 && symbolx2y2 == symbolx2y1 && symbolx2y1 == "Circle")drawCircle(g);
     if(symbolx2y0 == symbolx2y1 && symbolx2y2 == symbolx2y1 && symbolx2y1 == "Cross")drawCross(g);
}
public String setSymbolx0y0(String symbolx0y0){
    return this.symbolx0y0 = symbolx0y0;

}
public String setSymbolx1y0(String symbolx1y0){
    this.symbolx1y0 = symbolx1y0;
    return symbolx1y0;
}
public String setSymbolx2y0(String symbolx2y0){
    this.symbolx2y0 = symbolx2y0;
    return symbolx2y0;
}
public String setSymbolx0y1(String symbolx0y1){
    this.symbolx0y1 = symbolx0y1;
    return symbolx0y1;
}
public String setSymbolx1y1(String symbolx1y1){
    this.symbolx1y1 = symbolx1y1;
    return symbolx1y1;
}
public String setSymbolx2y1(String symbolx2y1){
    this.symbolx2y1 = symbolx2y1;
    return symbolx2y1;
}
public String setSymbolx0y2(String symbolx0y2){
    this.symbolx0y2 = symbolx0y2 ;
    return symbolx0y2;
}
public String setSymbolx1y2(String symbolx1y2){
    this.symbolx1y2 = symbolx1y2;
    return symbolx1y2;
}
public String setSymbolx2y2(String symbolx2y2){
    this.symbolx2y2 = symbolx2y2;
    return symbolx2y2;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

1. `symbolx2y2 == "Circle"` is not how `String` comparison works in Java, you should be using something like `"Circle".equals(symbolx2y2)` instead.  That goes for `symbolx1y1 == symbolx2y2` as well.
2. `g` is never assigned a value, so it's going to be `null`, besides, this is not how custom painting works in Swing.  See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.  Having said that, based on your code, I wouldn't use it, instead, I'd display a dialog with what ever message you want to display. See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.
3. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details
4. `Thread thread = new Thread();` isn't doing anything and is basically a waste
5. You should be ensuring that your UI is created and manipulated from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
6. Avoid extending directly from `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class and are simply locking yourself into a single use case.  Better to start with something like a `JPanel` and add this to an instance of `JFrame` or what ever container you want